# Excel Macro to copy rows from one file to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy certain columns (A,B and E) from one workbook to another. I wrote the following  Macro, with the help of cool people here at stackoverflow, but this code is not copying the table headings like "Study Room 2100E - Friday, Nov 30 2012"

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:B" & lr)
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:B")

Set sourceColumn2 = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("E" & lr)
Set targetColumn2 = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
sourceColumn2.Copy Destination:=targetColumn2

End Sub
```

This is the [source file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4tcwo2ZvQCRWkxxOU5xOGNSY2s):

This is what my [current target](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4tcwo2ZvQCRckdzZ25IZmlaZU0) file: **(EDITED TO INCLUDE CORRECT LINK 6:58PM EST Dec 11)**

This is my [desired target](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4tcwo2ZvQCRV0l2SmxHZkh6NFU) file:

The Source file consists of many tables with separate table headings. As you can tell, the rows A,B and E of the tables are being copied but the table headings are not being copied. How can I modify my code so my current target file looks like my desired target file? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get the result you do is that the headers are merged cells, 4 cells wide and the copy/paste of 2 columns does not capture the values from these cells (don't know why).

A work around is to copy the *Values* first (via a variant array) and then copy/paste special the formats.

This will create headers with merged cells 2 cells wide.  You will need to adjust the headers after the copy operation.

Note, you should declare *all* your variables

```
Option Explicit ' First line in Module

Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
    Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
    Dim sourceColumn2 As Range, targetColumn2 As Range
    Dim lr As String  ' <-- don't know what this is for, left it in as it's in your OP
    Dim rw As Range

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A:B" & lr)
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:B").Resize(sourceColumn.Rows.Count)

    ' Copy values
    targetColumn = sourceColumn.Value
    ' Copy Format
    sourceColumn.Copy
    targetColumn.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    Set sourceColumn2 = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("E" & lr)
    Set targetColumn2 = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
    sourceColumn2.Copy Destination:=targetColumn2

    ' Adjust Headers
    For Each rw In targetColumn.Rows
        If rw.MergeCells Then
            rw.Resize(1, 4).Merge
            ' Appy cell format to headers here if required
            rw.Font.Size = 18
            ' etc ...
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I cannot believe it's taken me till 2014 to thank you for your kindness. My bad. Happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:G" & lr)
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("A:G")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C:D").EntireColumn.Delete
Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm sorry I've taken so long to thank you. Cheers!